# Liferay: How can a portlet automatically poll for updates so multiple instances are synchronized without refresh?

Tags: liferay, chat, data-synchronization

I'm looking to modify one of my existing portlets which is used concurrently by many users to be able to automatically poll for updates and pull down the latest data in that portlet. That way users don't have to refresh the page to see the new data. In otherwords its automatically checking for new data every 10 seconds and refreshing the data.

Almost like a chat client but its pulling down a JSON object every 10 seconds asynchronously.

Comment: you can use quartz scheduler.http://www.apoorvaprakash.in/2011/02/liferay-scheduler.html

Answer (score 1):

No problem. On the browser side, query `<portlet:resourceURL/>` - this goes to the resource-serving phase of your portlet. From there you can deliver any content type you want (kind of like a servlet)

On the server side, you'll need to query for updated data from all the different users, but that's something independent of the portlet spec and rather considered business logic.

Comment: I think question was asking about how to auto poll any method on liferay. Something like: there will be any method on controller and which implements like polling interface and can set time for that and returns accordingly. Actually I am also looking for that type of polling technique. I think resource URL may not help on those cases, right?

Comment: well, with resourceURL you can implement this mechanism manually. There's also the poller mechanism that is used by, e.g., Liferay's Chat portlet. I'll leave the instructions of how to hook into that mechanism to somebody who has done it already.